# nsp command not found

Tags: node.js, npm, installation

I have installed nsp module using

> npm install nsp

But when I try to run any nsp commands like

> nsp check --reporter summary

I get

> nsp: command not found

I see nsp in npm list as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are installing it locally. Try:

`node_modules/.bin/nsp check --reporter summary`

Does it work?

Comment: Looks like it works but not completely. I get 'Access Denied' with a ProxyException. Must be network issue. Thanks for your response.

Comment: you're welcome. I recommend to add shortcut to package.json so you can run it faster with `npm run nsp`, for example:
https://github.com/ndaidong/article-parser/blob/master/package.json#L20

Answer (score 0):

You need to install it globally by adding the **-g**

```
npm install nsp -g
```

Comment: Not recommended. The right way is add shortcut to the scripts section in package.json so that you can call `npm run check` for example.